# How to properly chain concatMaps in Angular RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, concatmap

```
    this.route.params.pipe(
      concatMap((param) => {
        const ein = param['nonprofit-id'];
        return this.nonprofitService.getNonprofit(ein).pipe(
          concatMap((nonprofit) => {
            this.nonprofit = nonprofit;
            const ratingID = nonprofit.currentRating?.ratingID ? nonprofit.currentRating.ratingID : -1;
            return this.nonprofitService.getRatingForNonprofit(ein, ratingID).pipe(
              concatMap((nonprofitRating) => {
                this.nonprofitRating = nonprofitRating;
                const causeID = this.nonprofit?.cause?.causeID ? this.nonprofit?.cause?.causeID : 0;
                return this.nonprofitService.getSimilarNonprofits(causeID);
              })
            );
          })
        );
      })
    ).subscribe((response) => {
      this.similarNonprofits = response;
    });
```

I would like to know if the above is the correct way to chain concatMaps in Angular RxJS. The other two calls rely on the "nonprofit" in question being retrieved so that its object can be returned. Rating and Similar Nonprofits can be retrieved at the same time so I was thinking there would be some way I could do this without nesting those concatMaps within each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be using all the previous values it usualy ends with nesting more and more chains but in this case it seems already too complicated so you can `map()` each inner Observable into an array (or object) like the following:

```
this.route.params.pipe(
  concatMap((param) => {
    const ein = param['nonprofit-id'];
    return this.nonprofitService.getNonprofit(ein).pipe(
      map(nonprofit => [ein, nonprofit]),
    );
  ),
  concatMap(([ein, nonprofit]) => {
    const ratingID = ...;
    this.nonprofitService.getRatingForNonprofit(ein, ratingID).pipe(
      map(nonprofitRating => [nonprofitRating, ein, nonprofit]),
    );
  }),
  concatMap(([nonprofitRating, ein, nonprofit]) => {
    const causeID = ...;
    return this.nonprofitService.getSimilarNonprofits(causeID).pipe(
      map(similar => [similar, nonprofitRating, ein, nonprofit]),
    );
  }
).subscribe(([similar, nonprofitRating, ein, nonprofit]) => { ... });
```

Obviously, you don't have to unwrap each array passed as a parameter to consecutive `concatMap`s but I hope you get the point.

Comment: Ahhh, so if I do it side-by-side as parameters in the pipe function, the value that's passed down as the parameter for the arrow function is just what's mapped in the return of the previous concatMap?

Comment: yes, each array is a single `next` notification that will be processed by the following `concatMap`

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from @martin's answer, I'd suggest to use `forkJoin` to combine the last two `concatMap`s to a single request since they do not depend on each other. This would also trigger the requests in parallel and might help in improving performance (though miniscule).

I've also replaced the ternary operator with the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```js
this.route.params.pipe(
  concatMap((param: any) => {
    const ein = param['nonprofit-id'];
    return this.nonprofitService.getNonprofit(ein).pipe(
      map((nonprofit) => ([ein, nonprofit]))
    );
  }),
  concatMap(([ein, nonprofit]) => 
    forkJoin([
      this.nonprofitService.getRatingForNonprofit(ein, (nonprofit.currentRating?.ratingID ?? -1)),
      this.nonprofitService.getSimilarNonprofits(ein, (this.nonprofit?.cause?.causeID ?? 0))
    ]).pipe(
      map(([nonprofitRating, similarNonprofits]) => ([
        nonprofit,
        nonprofitRating,
        similarNonprofits
      ]))
    )
  )
).subscribe({
  next: ([nonprofit, nonprofitRating, similarNonprofits]) => {
    this.nonprofit = nonprofit;
    this.nonprofitRating = nonprofitRating;
    this.similarNonprofits = similarNonprofits;
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

You could also define an object with the properties to avoid using destructuring syntax with multiple elements.